# Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getPath does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

When I declare the route like this:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(route('admin'));
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 
    'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Dashboard@index')->name('admin');
});
```

I receive the following error.

> Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getPath does not exist.

However, when I declare the routes like this, it works fine.

```php
Route::get('/', 'Admin\Dashboard@index')->middleware('auth');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Dashboard@index')->name('admin');
});
```

I want to use the first example not to repeat the route. It seems that it is the function/redirect that is giving problem. Is it because the system is trying to cache the routes, and as routes with closure don't cache it gives an error?

PS: I'm not using the method getPath() anywhere.

Comment: What about if you use this syntax `return redirect()->route('admin');`?

Comment: Also not work. Not even this works: return 'test';

Comment: And this one? `Route::redirect('/', '/admin');`. Also you can run `php artisan route:list` to check what laravel say about that route.

Comment: Same error. This command say that the Action is Closure, the Method is GET|HEAD, the URI is / and the Middleware is Web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you replace `return redirect(route('admin'));` by `return redirect()->route('admin');`.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('admin');
});
```

Comment: But i'm not importing this class and i'm not using the method getPath(). I'm just defining that get route.

Comment: @DiegoVieira  I updated my post. I hope my answer can help you.